# Java. Write a Pattern to split command line to the gaps

Tags: java, split, command-line-arguments, design-patterns

Please, help write a Pattern to split the command line only on the spaces that lie between the command and its arguments:

**my code:**

```
String commands = "gedit /home/ant/Documents/Txt Books/1.txt /home/ant/Documents/1.txt";

String[] arrCommands = Pattern.compile("\\\s[^\\\s\\\w]").split(commands);

for (int i = 0; i < arrCommands.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(arrCommands[i]);
}
```

**program gives the following result:**

> gedit
>  home/ant/Documents/Txt Books/1.txt
>   home/ant/Documents/1.txt

**and it is necessary to make it so:**

> gedit
>  /home/ant/Documents/Txt Books/1.txt
>   /home/ant/Documents/1.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this regex to split

```
\\s+(?=[^\\w\\s])
```

---

In your regex `[^\\\s\\\w]` would eat the **first** character after space..hence the result..

Use `lookahead` which would only check for the pattern but would not eat it...

Answer (score 1):

YOU COULD ALSO TRY TO  SPLIT THE  STRING using the    split() method

for example :

Please, help write a Pattern to split the command line only on the spaces that lie between the command and its arguments:

```
String commands = "gedit /home/ant/Documents/Txt Books/1.txt /home/ant/Documents/1.
String[] commandsToArray=commands.split("\\s+");//this wil ignore multiples whitespaces
```

Comment: result gedit
home/ant/Documents/Txt Books/1.txt
home/ant/Documents/1.txt

Comment: need: gedit
/home/ant/Documents/Txt Books/1.txt
/home/ant/Documents/1.txt